# Grid/Layout in Twitter Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap 3 and have read through their documentation and understand how to nest columns but I have a different problem. I'm trying to create a col-md-8 carousel [which I KNOW how to do] and a col-md-4 next to it that contains 2 rows [not sure I should call them rows] with total height equal to same height as carousel [450px].

As a newbie, I'm not allowed to post an image but please see www.123rf.com which has a good example of what I'm trying to achieve [they have a carousel on left which will be my col-md-8 and then the 3 boxes on right [mine will only have 2], which will be contained in my col-md-4 but I don't know the best way to get those boxes [are they just rows?]. I only need help creating those boxes in second column.

My code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">  
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
A bunch of code here for carousel which WORKS beautifully, so no help needed here!

</div> <!--End carousel col-md-8 --> 

Now the part I'm confused on. Should I use panels or maybe even list groups? Not sure that's the best way to do this...OR should I do the following and then just adjust heights in CSS?:
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">Top Box</div>
<div class="col-md-12">Bottom Box</div> 
</div> 
</div> <!--End col-md-4 div-->
```

Then I'll close all the divs for the above row and start my marketing content. Not sure if I need to "clear" anything but starting another container > row > col-md-12 seems to work for the content that follows the above carousel row.

I don't want just ANY solution that works - would love to know the BEST WAY to do this, so I'm learning to use Bootstrap 3 properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That is not a layout possible with un-modified Bootstrap CSS (any version).

That example (rf123) is a non-responsive site where the slider is a known height. So you don't have to figure out what to do with the layout at different widths. The images inside the three rows on the right are 1/3rd of that height minus the two dividers.

If you want create a layout like that with Bootstrap you need, in my opinion, to be familiar with Bootstrap intimately so you can modify the grid gutter and also figure out fallbacks for crappy browsers depending on what's going on with the two boxes inside the col-md-4.

http://jsbin.com/OCiPofu/2/

If you don't want a large 30px gap between the columns, you have to modify the gutters. In this type of layout to make it responsive-ish, I believe you need a script to make the col-md-4 height equal to the height of whatever is inside the col-md-8 and then use percentages to figure out the math. You could also just make sure that the slider doesn't get smaller and always stays at a given height and you don't need a script, just put the sizes on the boxes in the min-widths. The mobile version of the layout is not figured out in this example.

Occasionally with design ideas based on non-responsive examples you have an extraordinary amount of media queries to screw with, it's better to figure out a way to accomplish the same goal by looking at responsively designed sites and learning from those.

Comment: Though you could be able to use display:table etc., and do something like that at the min-width and then stack at mobile.

Comment: Thanks Christina. Yes, I know the 123rf example isn't built w/Bootstrap but it was best example I saw of what I wanted to achieve. I was challenged to find an example of any Bootstrap 3 site design w/similar layout. My carousel is a set height (450px) and even when I don't specify a height it seems to scale fine because my photos are all sized to be same width and 450px high. It's those boxes giving me problems. I'll try to fool around w/Panels or unordered lists and style w/CSS to see if that works. I'm ok with the 30px gutter bw carousel and second column - I actually want that there.